# Modal Bootstrap / Multiple modal on one-page / modal-open Class

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I've got a serious issue with modal from Bootstrap.

When I open a modal box in my website, there's absolutly no problem (the modal-open class is correctly added on the body) the modal is correct, shade ok and content clear :

`<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal_GA">buttonOpenMe</button>`

When I close it manualy, it's ok too :

`<button type="button" class="close2" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
 <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><p class="TxtClose">CLOSE</p>`

In my first modal, I've got two others buttons to check my previous & next projects (my website is a one-page). 

And this is what i want to do :
action 1) open modal#1
action 2) scroll & click on next project
action 3) close modal#1
action 4) open modal#2, etc...

`<button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal_Animations">
CloseThis
</button>`

My body had an added class called "modal-open" when a modal box is opened. But when I'm already in the first modal & I want to go into the second project (modal#2), he appears but my scroll is locked and my body lost his "modal-open" class.

I think data-dismiss="modal" clear everything. But when I add manually (with inspector) the class "modal-open" on my body when the second modal is opened, everything works.

So I tried to fix this with a lot a solution from forum post & nothing really works.

I think I had to look for this type of snippets for adding the class on the body automatically, something like that :

```
    $(document)
.on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', function () { 
    $(document.body).addClass('modal-open') 
})
.on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () { 
    $(document.body).removeClass('modal-open') 
})
```

But actually, everything failed, obviously!

How can I fix this?

If you want to take a look to my online test version: http://bg-portfolio.com/bg_test/index.php , scroll and click on the first project "Gamers Assembly 2017", then scroll and click on "Projet suivant" (next project). The bug will appear!

PS: I'm working with Bootstrap v3.3.7 (and when I paste news files, everything is broken, so for this website, I just want to stay under this version for now)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe could be more convenient, change a little bit the way as you show/hide your modals for each next/previous portfolio item.

```
<button type="button" class="close2" data-actual="#Modal_GA" data-target="#Modal_Animations">
   <span aria-hidden="true">&gt;</span><p class="TxtClose">PROJET SUIVANT</p>
</button>
```

Then you can use only 1 simple jquery function:

```
  $('.close2').click(function() {
    var actualModal = $(this).attr('data-actual');
    var newModal = $(this).attr('data-target');

    $(actualModal).modal('hide');
    $(newModal).modal('show');
  });
```

Note that you don't need any more create a script for each portfolio item, in this way you will save time load and resource for the JS in the browser.

Comment: Hey @JoseMolina, thanks for your help too.

I tryed your solution and after many manipulation to fix this bug with your snippets the bug stay.

There's something new with this code, the second section open correctly but closes instantaneously afterwards. I'm looking for if there is not a duplicate in the values ​​of my modal button :

- open section#1
- scroll down
- click btn2 (> section#2)
- close section #1
- open section #2
- close section #2

Maybe this came from data-dismiss="modal" or data-toggle="modal". I'm keeping this way to find a solution then. Thanks for your help

Comment: You are welcome @Nóva 

Are you sure you used the button code exactly as I put? Because I remove the data-dismiss and data-toggle.

I have something like that in my website www.josemolinaresume.com in the portfolio section, if you want take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You've added the event listeners twice:

When I view source I can see the following on lines 583 and 1046:

```
$(document)
.on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', function () { 
    $(document.body).addClass('modal-open') 
})
.on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () { 
    $(document.body).removeClass('modal-open') 
})
```

I quickly removed one of the event listeners in Chromes Inspect Tool.

Right click the *button* in the modal you mentioned > *Inspect* > *Event Listeners* > *click* > then delete one of the *div#Modal_GA,modal.fade.in* event listeners. The next modal now scrolled correctly for me.

I assume, therefore, that by removing one of the two duplicated blocks, you will remove this second listener, which is basically firing twice and messing up your second modal...

Comment: Hi @RichardDunn, thanks for the help.

I tryed this, and it work when I delete this manualy, like you. For the first, double javascript, it's ok. I was trying many things to fix this bug & that's why I let this mistake but it's ok now. 

You're on the good way I think.
> div#Modal_GA,modal.fade.in is 
I have the impression that this element is created dynamically in duplicate. After checking, I did search and I didn't find this item duplicated in my code.

I'm keep looking for this bug. Thanks for your help

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's added 'dynamically' it's still registering the event listener in the DOM twice. You can further test this is the issue by removing the snippet from the 'dynamic' code, and adding it 'statically' on your index page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1>Bootstrap 4x multiple modals in one page</h1>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg">Large modal</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg1">Large modal1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg2">Large modal2</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg3">Large modal3</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg4">Large modal4</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg5">Large modal5</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg6">Large modal6</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg7">Large modal7</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg8">Large modal8</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg9">Large modal9</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg10">Large modal10</button>


<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myLargeModalLabel">Large modal</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myLargeModalLabel">Large modal1</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myLargeModalLabel">Large modal2</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel1"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myLargeModalLabel">Large modal3</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg4" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel1"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myLargeModalLabel">Large modal4</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg5" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel1"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myLargeModalLabel">Large modal5</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg6" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel1"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myLargeModalLabel">Large modal6</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg7" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel1"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myLargeModalLabel">Large modal7</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg8" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel1"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myLargeModalLabel">Large modal8</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg9" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel1"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myLargeModalLabel">Large modal9</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg10" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel1"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myLargeModalLabel">Large modal10</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `modal-open` class gets removed after the modal has finished animating closed, but added by the other modal just as it opens. Unfortunately these animations overlap. This means that the `modal-open` class is added by the opening modal and then quickly removed by the closing modal (as I understand it).

Hooking into the late events of the modal (specifically `shown.bs.modal`, which is fired when the opening animation ends) should help you here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events

```
$( '#modal1' ).on( 'shown.bs.modal', function(){
    document.body.classList.add( 'modal-open' );
});
$( '#modal2' ).on( 'shown.bs.modal', function(){
    document.body.classList.add( 'modal-open' );
});
```

Tested and working over here